# How do i get all combination in prolog?

Tags: prolog

this is my code, I don't understand why this does not look like what I thought

```
com([],[]).
com([H|T1],[H|T2]):-
    com(T1,T2).
com([_|T1],T2):-
    com(T1,T2).

three([X1,X2|T]) :-
    X2 is X1 + 1,
    (
        T = []               
    ;   three([X2|T])    
    ).
```

then I tried "findall(Tests, (com([6,7,8,8,9],Tests),three(Tests),Length(Test,N)), N>=3,Alltests)", this is to find all possible cases that continuous number with at least length 3，

'com' return all the tests

'three' is to find all continuous number with at least length 3.

but, the results were wrong.

```
[trace] findall(..,....,[[6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]])
```

why I just got one [6,7,8,9] and [7,8,9], it should return both I think

Comment: Please try to paste the **exact** queries you were using. The one you gave here sure didn't give the results you quoted.

Comment: I‘m sorry for my mistake, I thought I typed the list with [7,7,8,8,9], but it actually was [6,7,8,9,8] .........

Answer (score 1):

> `findall(Tests, (com([6,7,8,8,9],Tests),three(Tests),Length(Test,N)), N>=3,Alltests)`

- You have `Test` instead of `Tests` here, so it's a different variable.
- And `Length` with a capital needs to be `length`
- And you have `N>=3` outside the `()` so you are using `findall/4` instead of `findall/3`.

With those changes, it seems to work for me:

```
?- findall(Tests, (com([6,7,8,8,9],Tests),three(Tests),length(Tests,N), N>=3),Alltests).

Alltests = [[6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: I‘m sorry for my mistake, I thought I typed the list with [7,7,8,8,9], but it actually was [6,7,8,9,8] .......

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to work alright:

```
?- com([6,7,8,8,9],Tests), three(Tests), length(Tests,N), N >= 3.
   N = 4, Tests = [6,7,8,9]
;  N = 3, Tests = [6,7,8]
;  N = 4, Tests = [6,7,8,9]
;  N = 3, Tests = [6,7,8]
;  N = 3, Tests = [7,8,9]
;  N = 3, Tests = [7,8,9]
;  false.
```

Tip: always do the pure parts first; aggregate later.

Comment: I‘m sorry for my mistake, I thought I typed the list with [7,7,8,8,9], but it actually was [6,7,8,9,8]

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to give an easy way to define three/1

```
three(Lst) :-
    LstDigits = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    between(3, 9, Len),
    length(Lst, Len),
    append([_, Lst, _], LstDigits).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- three(L).
L = [1,2,3] ;
L = [2,3,4] ;
L = [3,4,5] ;
L = [4,5,6] ;
L = [5,6,7] ;
L = [6,7,8] ;
L = [7,8,9] ;
L = [1,2,3,4] ;
L = [2,3,4,5] ;
etc.
```